# Explain how a recursive Haskell list function works?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I know what the following function does I would just like an explanation of how it works and the calculations that take place:

```
sponge :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
sponge 0 xs = xs
sponge n [] = []
sponge n (x:xs) = sponge (n-1) xs
```

I just seem to have lost the plot with it all now :(

Any help to get me back on track would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: You say you have lost the plot and are off track, but you give no clue as to what it is you don't understand. That's important, because this code requires only a very rudimentary understanding of Haskell. So is there syntax here that you don't understand?

Comment: The question was edited in a misleading way. By adding the word "recursion", which the OP did not use, it leaves the impression that it is recursion that the OP is having trouble with, but we don't know that the OP is having trouble with recursion ... or even that the OP knows what recursion is or is aware that the function is recursive.

Comment: @Jim Balter The word recursion was added so we can find the answer later, categorized, as it is, under the appropriate terms. Titles like "explain this function" are not searchable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a recursive function over two variables. You can break it apart line-by-line to understand it:

```
sponge :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

Two arguments, one an `Int`, one a list of some elements.

```
sponge 0 xs = xs
```

The base case. If the `Int` argument is zero, just return the list argument unmodified.

```
sponge n [] = []
```

Another base case, if the list is empty, immediately return the empty list.

```
sponge n (x:xs) = sponge (n-1) xs
```

Finally, the inductive step. If the list is non-empty (i.e. made up of at least one element and a tail, denoted by `x:xs`), then the result is `sponge` called on `n-1` and the tail of the list.

So what will this function do? It will return the tail of the list after dropping `n` elements. It is the same as the `drop` function:

```
> drop 10 [1..20]
[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

And

```
> sponge 10 [1..20]
[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

In fact, we can ask QuickCheck to confirm:

```
> quickCheck $ \n xs -> sponge n xs == drop n xs
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 7 tests and 5 shrinks):    
-1
[()]
```

Ah! They're different. When `n` is negative! So we can modify the property relating the two functions:

```
> quickCheck $ \n xs -> n >= 0 ==> sponge n xs == drop n xs
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

So your function behaves like drop, for cases when `n` is positive.

---

Here's a trace of the intermediate values of `n` and `xs`, obtained via the [hood debugger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hood):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It takes two parameters, as you can see: an Int and a list. It pattern-matches to distinguish three cases: 1) the Int is zero; 2) the list is empty; or, 3) the Int is not zero nor is the list empty.

In case 1 it returns the list; in case 2, it returns the empty list (which is what the second parameter was anyway); in case 3, it recursively calls itself with original Int parameter *minus 1* and the original list *minus its first element*.

It looks a lot like "drop" from the Prelude.